# How to repeat a value specified number of times in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to repeat a value specified number of times in Google Sheets, assuming no overlap or ignoring overlap if any.

Screenshot of the example with **ID** in column B and **Nights** in column C.

Trying to reach desired output (column D) with reservation ID repeated the specified number of nights.

Link to [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hH7OcWG0_7taZ8gnOvn-itGkom7fB_QNzHzAddfm0cM/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: Sheet]

Comment: Please provide a link to the spreadsheet containing the sample data set above. Otherwise, you'd be expecting  the volunteer contributors here to start their own sheet and enter your data themselves before they could even begin to consider a solution. And that will deter many. Help us to help you by sharing a link.

Comment: Also, what is the maximum stay (i.e., Col-C number) possible?

Comment: Sorry about that, here is the Sheets link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hH7OcWG0_7taZ8gnOvn-itGkom7fB_QNzHzAddfm0cM/edit?usp=sharing

Well, it's a rental property, so max stay for our use case is until next guest checks in (in other words - number of empty cells below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sheet is "Comment only." But try deleting everything from Col D (including the header) and placing the following formula into cell D1:

`=ArrayFormula({"ID Full Stay"; IF(A2:A="",,IF(ROW(A2:A)>(VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A),FILTER(ROW(C2:C),C2:C<>""),1,TRUE) + VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A),FILTER({ROW(C2:C),C2:C-1},C2:C<>""),2,TRUE)),,VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A),FILTER({ROW(C2:C),B2:B},C2:C<>""),2,TRUE)))})`

This one formula will produce the header (which you can change as you like within the formula itself) and all results for all rows.